# Graph API search for all Swedish companies

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Is it possible somehow to use the Graph to search for all swedish companies that have a facebook-page? 
I've tried a little by searching for pages with the query "sweden", but i only get pages then that contains the string "sweden".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the closest I got after fiddling with the graph API, places around Stockholm, not really sure with units the `distance` parameters is using. You could maybe filter the results yourself on the category "Local business".

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=place&type=place&center=59.3,18.0&distance=1000
```

There should be a `access_token` parameter too but i think Facebook will add that if your browse to the URL with browser that is logged into Facebook.

Also it seams like you need to use pagination URLs to fetch all results.